# NTILE() in hive is getting stuck at 99%

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running the below query in hive :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database1.table2
AS SELECT A.company,A.amount,
NTILE(100) OVER(PARTITION BY A.company ORDER BY A.amount DESC) as pct
FROM (select company, amount from database1.table1
where trim(INDICATOR) = 'Debit' and trim(company)='1000' and amount IS NOT NULL)A;
```

The above query is running perfectly for 7M data. But while running the same for 122M, the **query stops at 99%**.

Comment: Bad data or memory issue ?

Comment: this could be case of data skewing, one of your nodes has more data that rest of.